# Passing Value to a Another View: Using State and Binding In SwiftUI

Tags: swift

I am trying to pass a value from my View LingView, to another View ContentView. I have a state variable in the login view as such:

```
@State var userName: String = ""
  @State private var password: String = ""
```

I then pass the value from the Content View Constructor in two places:
This is in RootView

```
var body: some View {
      ContentView(userName: LoginView().$userName)
      .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $authenticator.needsAuthentication) {
        LoginView()
          .environmentObject(authenticator) // see note
      }
  }
```

This is in Content View:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(userName: Login().$userName)
            .environmentObject(Authenticator())
    }
}
```

I want to use the variable to pass into the getPictures() function that a database file uses. I am kind of confused as to what I am suppose to do. The parent view in this case would be LoginView correct? I am unsure why I keep getting: Cannot find type 'userName' in scope.

```
@Binding var userName: String
    
    print(userName)
    
    
    var pictureURL = DbHelper().getPictures()
```

After running the following code. I understand that you should make state private to a View, but in this case how would I pass the state value to the content view? The LoginView does not call the ContentView directly. Maybe I don't understand Bindings and State, but I have read this article: https://learnappmaking.com/binding-swiftui-how-to/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initialising two separate login views. The username binding passed to `ContentView` is therefore a different binding to the one you have under `.fullscreenCover`

To make it work, you can declare a `State` variable in `RootView`,

```
@State private var userName: String = "" // In RootView
```

then pass its binding to both `ContentView` and `LoginView`.

```
@Binding var userName: String // In ContentView and LoginView
```

Simply put, `State` holds your actual username value, while `Binding` gives you a method of seeing and changing it from somewhere else.

Comment: So it is saying $userName is not in scope. I can't declare a state variable named usrName in ContentView because that is where I am declaring my binding. How do I pass in a parameter to the ContentView that is under previews?

Comment: For the previewprovider, you can give the ContentView initialiser a constant binding. e.g. `ContentView(userName: .constant("someUserName"))`